# Cant set dynamic array bottom c++

Tags: c++

**I try to make border of 2d array but button not set**

[my Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk6rD.png)

```
    backGround='\'';
    screenBorder='#';
    w = 25;
    h = 25;
```

```cpp
    void fillScreen(void){
        for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
            for(int a=0;a<h;a++){
                screenMap[i][a]=backGround;
            }
            screenMap[0][i]=screenBorder;//up
            screenMap[w-1][i]=screenBorder;//down
            screenMap[i][0]=screenBorder;//left
            screenMap[i][h-1]=screenBorder;//right
        }
    }
```

i want to set bottom symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
bool isBorder(int col, int row, int width, int height)
{
    return col == 0 || col == width - 1 || row == 0 || row == height - 1;
}

void fillScreen(void)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
        {
            screenMap[col][row]= isBorder(col, row, w, h) ? screenBorder: backGround;
        }
    }
}
```

It is clearer, easier to read and extensible

Comment: Yes. Thank you, thats realy cool code! But you made a little mistake but nothing
```cpp
screenMap[col][row]= isBorder(col, row, w, h) ? screenBorder : backGround  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Last iteration of this loop: `for(int i=0;i<w;i++){`
When internal loop is exacuted it overrides results of earlier iterations.

So to fix your code internal loop should not be executed during last iteration of external loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool isBorder(int col, int row, int width, int height)
{
    return col == 0 || col == width - 1 || row == 0 || row == height - 1;
}

void fillScreen(void)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
        {
            screenMap[col][row]= isBorder(col, row, w, h) ? screenBorder : backGround  ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer